# Execute cUrl request

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to php & cUrl's so I was wondering if someone knows how to get the following command executed using php.

```
curl "http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?action=confirm" -H "Origin: http://www.mywebsite.com" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Referer: http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?action=confirm" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data "confirmed=yes&id=14&from=&to=TestPerson" --compressed
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if this beginner stuff. I'm just trying to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite like this..

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    $curlconf = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => "http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?action=confirm",
        CURLOPT_POST           => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
            'confirmed' => 'yes',
            'id' => 14,
            'from'=>'',
            'to'=>'TestPerson',
        )
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlconf);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: As a result I'm getting the html of the page
But the cUrl doesn't seem to do it's work

Comment: Yes that is the response which you get after posting the parameters.

Comment: I've found my problem, You need to be logged in. How to send a -H with this aswell? (That includes my cookie + phpsessid

Answer (score 1):

You have a PHP extension for that : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: So if I put the full cUrl in the text file it should work? or do I need to modify it?

Comment: This extension offers you a wrapper to do the same things in command line mode. But you have to integrate it in your PHP code. Is it a cron job ? Your curl is triggered from a web page ?